# How come SNAP does not have option chain?

Tags: options, equities, short-selling

I want to buy put options on the newly issued SNAP stock (Snapchat).
How come the option chain is still empty? it's been a few days since the IPO.

Comment: Not every stock has an option traded on it.

Comment: Patience! Patience! It takes at least a week, sometimes longer. SNAP is only 3 days old.

Comment: Options will be listed this Friday. Source: ```http://www.cboe.com/blogs/options-hub/2017/03/02/snapchat-%28snap%29-ipo-is-here!```

Comment: Could you make that an answer @LocalVolatility ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Options will be listed this Friday, [source](http://www.cboe.com/blogs/options-hub/2017/03/02/snapchat-(snap)-ipo-is-here!).